# Where do I find my Consumer Key for Twitter Fabric Digits for a webapp

Tags: web-applications, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

**Visiting https://fabric.io/onboard there is no tab for web. How do I obtain the Consumer Key.**

**Update:**   I am now using Firebase Phone Auth , Which is essentially Digits.

Comment: Hey have you got consumer key ? i have same issue

Comment: I am now using firebase phone auth , which is fundamentally Digits

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here.

I may have answered you via DM into our Twitter handle. Web apps aren't officially supported by Digits, the web component of Digits is designed to be a complement to a Digits account on a mobile app. However, you can always use the instructions here for web based onboarding: https://fabric.io/kits

Comment: yes you did, and i did get it running to a point of starting the digits flow. However running into more hurdles in my journey to get digits as a default login method on my webapp.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same scenario for my web app.

As per digits suggestion we can use consumer key of Android/Apple.

I have tested it working good.